# Does the conservation of energy not contradict Newton's $3^{\text{rd}}$ law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Suppose "ball A" is flying with force F. The ball makes contact with "ball B" that has force 0. If the force applied to ball B is equal to the force that is applied to ball A then isn't there a total force of 2F? Doesn't that contradict the conservation of energy?

Comment: It looks like you have some serious misunderstandings about force and energy. First of all, something cannot be "flying with" a force - object fly with velocities, not forces. Similarly, it is meaningless to say that Ball B "has force" 0. Additionally, why would an increase in force imply an increase in energy?

Comment: @Locke you're getting downvotes because your question is unclear. It's kind of unfair since it's only unclear because you don't understand what force means. I advise either asking for an explanation of Newton's 3rd Law and Forces (and energy) or reading about it (https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force), then asking your question.

Comment: Forces describe interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Balls do not fly with force (I didn't think I'd type that today) but with *speed*. At a point of contact with another ball, a force can be applied on that ball by the first ball. Newton's third law states "For every force there is a force with equal magnitude, but opposite direction", so one ball would feel a force as they collided, and move in one direction, and the other ball would feel the same force in the opposite direction and move off in that direction. The total sum of the kinetic energy of the two balls before and after the collision would be the same (or less after, if energy was dissipated during the collision).